# devise dynamic flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, flash-message

I am using devise for authentication purpose and all functionalities are working fine.

When a user signs out, The flash message which displaying is `"Signed out successfully."`.This can be customized in devise.en.yml.

But I need this to be dynamic (like) "`user.email` signed out successfully". How to make devise flash messages to be dynamic?

Comment: Have you tried "%{user.email} signed out successfully" ?

Comment: I want to edit the line from devise.en.yml file?

Comment: Yes, I dunno if that will work, maybe you have to overwrite this part on devise to send the user for i18n to interpolate http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to display this thing.

To do this we want to create a 'devise' folder in controllers and create a new controller 'sessions', and do the rest of things.

I have given my code:

```
def create  
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "new")  
  session["resource_email"] = resource.email  
  flash[:notice] = "#{resource.email} signed in  successfully.."  
  sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)  
end

def destroy  
   flash[:notice] = "#{session["resource_email"]} signed out successfully.."  
   sign_out_and_redirect(resource_name)  
end
```